What is the difference between Eventss.import and Events.insert API endpoints in Google Calendar API?
I want to know the practical difference between the insert and import endpoints in Google Calendar API.
The documentation states that for the import endpoint

This operation is used to add a private copy of an existing event to a calendar.

I've used this endpoint, and provided the CalUID of the original event that I copied, but it does not seem to be any correlation between the copied event and its created copy. i.e Changing the copied event does not change the copy.
Any idea how that differs from the /insert endpoint?

Difference between Insert vs Import
Insert is creating an event out of thin air while Import is creating an event from a different source or calendar, or something that can be used as some sort of pseudo template for calendar. During the import process. It is more on creating another independent branch copy of the original and not creating a two way sync between calendars.
Import

This operation is used to add a private copy of an existing event to a calendar.

Insert

Creates an event.

Additional Insight (Use Case)
With this information at hand, it should differ in use cases. Most importantly when you are migrating a large set of events so you will have some pseudo templates and make your migrations easier. I can say that most of the use case for this is more on migrations. I would think that one is becoming a place holder for event details that is not part of the required parameters of the endpoint. Though I would agree with you that there is only a thin line of difference between these two endpoints.
On most recent exposure that I have to use this on my own projects and also use cases I found here on SO. I can see that it was a bridge to handle IcalUID. Which enables event and scheduling format exchange from different platforms.
Reference:
Calendar API - Import
Calendar API - Insert
ICALUID

I had provided these two links in my question. What is the practical difference between creating a new and copying an event if in the copy, you have to provide the entire body of the event you are creating. A Copy to me, you just provide the Id of the event you are copying from and that's it. Still can't figure out the diff.

Let me edit my answer for that. I now understand more about your question.

I added some information on my answer to better explai my perspective from my exposure from using both of 2 end points. Though I understand the lack of difference both. But what you can also think about is Insert - More on interacting on the platform directly, while import is bridging platforms and influencing the newer platform and transfer data as much as it could support without doing the trial and error which one sticks.

Thank you. Unfortunately, I still don't get the difference. To me, there's got to be a clear main point of difference. The reason I ask is because I am receiving this error https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/errors#403_forbidden_for_non-organizer on event.Import and I am not sure which shared property it is complaining about. I don't have any shared properties of the ones mentioned in the link populated in my API call's body.

If that would be the case I would suggest posting another question with the specific question at hand. This way the community will have information on your specific issue and your goals. The error you encountered might be coming from a lot of different things during an API call with more specific information at hand. You might get more information about your use case and might give shed some light with what answer you are looking for.
